# Compling C code in Netbeans IDE 6.9.1

Tags: c, netbeans, compilation, netbeans-6.9

Can anyone give me step by step tutorial on how to use netbeans to code and compile C code?
Also i have dev cpp but the formating is sick.
GCC is what i use.
Thanks much

Comment: Any particular platform?

Answer (score 0):

netbeans tutorial: http://cnd.netbeans.org/cnd-tutorial.html

In Ubuntu, I do the following:
- Create a new C/C++ project
- Import the sources
 - you already have makefiles (or cmake), netbeans you can configure that in the advanced screen. 
 - You can turn of automatic builds in the same advanced screen
 - and build using the normal build command.